# How to make SAP Commerce cloud OCC layer work with 3rd party identity provider Keycloak with OpenID Connect?

Tags: spring, spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud

We are developing a SAP Commerce cloud (v.2205) solution with a Spartacus storefront. We have to use a third party identity provider (in this case Keycloak) with OpenID Connect. In our case each request from the Spartacus storefront to a SAP Commerce Cloud OCC endpoint which has a `@Secured(USER_ROLE)` annotation should be validated against Keycloak. All users and their roles are automatically replicated from the SAP Commerce cloud to the Keycloak instance.

We know that the OCC layer uses the OOTB OAuth2 extension, which sets the commerce cloud itself as the identity provider, but it seems like there is no configuration available where we can just replace the OOTB "internal" identity provider with Keycloak OIDC. Furthermore we have tried to replace some of the security beans in the `oauth2-spring.xml` file but it doesn't look like the right solution as every security-related bean seems to be tightly connected with the OOTB logic and relies on the premise that the SAP Commerce Cloud is the only identity provider.

Is there a way to easily configure or extend the OCC layer to use Keycloak with OpenID Connect as the identity provider instead of the SAP Commerce cloud?

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to create a custom OAuth Token Granter extending AbstractTokenGranter that can process the id_token which is a JWT generated by the IDP, that enclosed the User information of the Authenticated user in Keycloak.
By making the same OAuth call (that is used to get an SAP OAuth token) we can achieve generating a OAuth token by using the JWT and grant_type as 'custom' after creating the User in SAP if doesn't exist.

If you have not already found this page. Referring [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2023/07/25/spartacus-sso-integration-with-microsoft-azure-active-directory/) this interesting blog that might be helpful, the IDP however here is Microsoft

Jump to this section of the above page for SAP Commerce related info
"SAP Commerce Implementation"

While this blog doesn't document handling user groups which is something worth extending.

I hope this is helpful..

Comment: AK M, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @mozway, thank you for your feedback, I have updated my answer with more context